# Compiler error while using Java Optional.map to string from boolean

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I'd like to re-write this code using `Optional`-like code:

```
private Order buildOrder(String field) {
    if (field.startsWith("-")) {
        return Order.desc(field.substring(1));
    }
    else {
        return Order.asc(field);
    }
}
```

Up to now, I've been able to code that:

```
private Order buildOrder(String field) {
    return Optional.of(field.startsWith("-"))
      .filter(Boolean::booleanValue)
      .map(() -> field.substring(1))  <<<<1>>>>
      .orElse(field)
      .map(Order.desc(field.substring(1)))
      .orElse(Order.asc(field));
}
```

But I'm getting this compilation error on `<<<<1>>>>`:

> Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method `apply(? super Boolean)`
>   Type mismatch: cannot convert from `String` to `? extends U`

Comment: replace `map(() -> field.substring(1))` with `map(f -> f.substring(1))`

Comment: `map` expects a `Function` to be passed in, while you are passing a lambda expression matching the `Supplier` functional interface.

Comment: By the way, despite the fact that I generally like the functional programming paradigm, I find your original code much more elegant.

Comment: The error is because the `Optional.map` method takes a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) as a parameter. From the definition of `Function`: Represents a function that _accepts one argument_ and produces a result. Your code has the missing argument.

Comment: Changing this to `Optional` does not make it more readable. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @MCEmperor it’s not like `field.startsWith("-")? Order.desc(field.substring(1)): Order.asc(field)` was less functional than, say, a hypothetical construct like `choice(field.startsWith("-"), Order.desc(field.substring(1)), Order.asc(field))` or even `choice(field.startsWith("-"), () -> Order.desc(field.substring(1)), () -> Order.asc(field))`. FP is not about the look of the syntax…

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid the boolean optional, which will simplify the method:

```
return Optional.of(field)
        .filter(f -> f.startsWith("-"))
        .map(s -> s.substring(1))
        .map(Order::desc)
        .orElseGet(() -> Order.asc(field));
```

Comment: But seriously, would you really recommend using this instead of, e.g. `return field.startsWith("-")? Order.desc(field.substring(1)): Order.asc(field);`?

Comment: @Holger That, as well as the first implementation in the question are better in many ways. I suppose I/we get trapped in answering the "how to do this using..." questions such as this one. Thanks for the remark, I think most of us have to try to keep our head out of the box a little more and (at least) include comments like that in answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your chain of methods will not work because you create an `Optional<Boolean>` and that cannot be mapped to a `String` derived from `field`. You need to have `Optional<String>`.
This is what I came with

```
private Order buildOrder(String field) {
    return Optional.of(field)
                .filter(f -> field.startsWith("-"))
                .map(f -> Order.desc(field.substring(1))
                .orElse(Order.asc(field));
}
```

Comment: `f->field.startWith` - then you are not actually using the `f` in the `Optional`, you could have just as well used the original `Optional<Boolean>`.

Comment: …and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745085/compiler-error-while-using-java-optional-map-to-string-from-boolean#comment96381260_54745461) applies here too.